# How do you find top level text nodes without duplication

Tags: r, xpath

I am scraping articles from different sites using R (rvest) that are often structured in different ways and would like to extract all html nodes (without duplication) whose descendants contain some text using xpath.

Simplifying, the structure could be something like (without the whitespaces that have been introduced for readbility):

```
<html>
<body>
    <a name="SomeMarker">
            <font style="FONT-SIZE: 12pt;"><b>Sports article</b></font>
    </a>
<div>
<b>This is possibly an article heading</b>
<font style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt;"> This is the <i>body</i> of the article.</font
<font style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt;"> It could have <i><b>interesting tags</b></i> embedded in the text</font>
</div>

<p id="SomeId"><b>This is another article heading</b>
    <font style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt;"> This is the <i>body</i> of the second article</font>
    <p><font style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt;"> It could have further <i><b><u>interesting tags</u></b></i> embedded in the text</font></p>
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

I have tried several different xpaths -- but they seem to always select duplicate nodes

```
"//a/following::*//*[text()]"
"//a/following::*/*[normalize-space(text())]"
"//a/following::*/*[normalize-space(text())]/parent::*"
```

and so on -- but all of them result in various permutations of text nodes

Currently, I get quite a few duplicate nodes, for e.g.:

```
[1] <div>\n<b>This is possibly an article heading</b><font style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt;"> This is the <i>body</i> of the article.</font><font style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt;"> It could have <i><b>interes ...
[2] <font style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt;"> This is the <i>body</i> of the article.</font>
[3] <i><b>interesting tags</b></i>
[4] <p id="SomeId"><b>This is another article heading</b><font style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt;"> This is the <i>body</i> of the second article.</font></p>\n
[5] <font style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt;"> This is the <i>body</i> of the second article.</font>
[6] <p><font style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt;"> It could have further <i><b><u>interesting tags</u></b></i> embedded in the text</font></p>
[7] <b><u>interesting tags</u></b>
```

Preferred outcome is to get only the top-level nodes whose descendants contain some text, ie, in the above case:

```
[1] <div><b>This is possibly an article heading</b><font style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt;"> This is the <i>body</i> of the article.</font><font style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt;"> It could have <i><b>interesting tags</b></i> embedded in the text</font></div>
[2] <p id="SomeId"><b>This is another article heading</b><font style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt;"> This is the <i>body</i> of the second article.</font><p><font style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt;"> It could have further <i><b><u>interesting tags</u></b></i> embedded in the text</font></p></p>
```

I know the xpath for just extracting the text -- I actually want the html nodes with the tags intact as I would like to do further processing on the top level nodes (for e.g. to extract the headings). Thanks much.

Comment: How about `//a/following::*[*[text()]][parent::body]`?

Comment: @supputuri thank you - that works! I do have a follow-up though, is there a way to structure the xpath without referencing `body` or any other tag except for `a`? thanks again!

Comment: Check first option in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1: Using following-sibling::

> //a/following-sibling::*[*[text()]]

Option 2: Using parent with following::

> //a/following::*[*[text()]][parent::body]

Comment: Let me know how it goes, with option 1.

Comment: This works mostly, I get three components (expecting 2 as in post) with the above example. For some reason, the <p> block is split into two different nodes.

Comment: So instead of 
`[2] <p id="SomeId"><b>This is another article heading</b><font style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt;"> This is the <i>body</i> of the second article.</font><p><font style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt;"> It could have further <i><b><u>interesting tags</u></b></i> embedded in the text</font></p></p>` 
I get 
`[2] <p id="SomeId"><b>This is another article heading</b><font style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt;"> This is the <i>body</i> of the second article.</font></p>\n
[3] <p><font style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt;"> It could have further <i><b><u>interesting tags</u></b></i> embedded in the text</font></p>`

Comment: Do you think para with another child para is allowed ?No, it doesn't. That's why the nested `<p>` will be displayed as another node.